# Understanding casting/conversion from pointer to multidimensional array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I'm playing around pointers and arrays, and i want to cast/convert a pointer to an array of *int* (allocated with *malloc*) to a multidimensional array of *int*.

I don't know why the following **C** program doesn't print the same number two times.

```
...
str->val = malloc(16);
int (*m)[4][4] = str->val;
printf("The number is %d, yes the number is %d", str->val[4+1], (*m)[1][1]);
...
```

Now, the first printed number is right, but the second one is not. I found other question on SO similar to mine, but i couldn't resolve my problem. I'm sorry for the possible duplication.

I have one more question: what's the difference between the following declarations?

```
int m[10];
int (*m)[10];
```

**EDIT:**

My problem is caused by a wrong declaration of the field *val* of my **struct**: I declared it as **char**.

Comment: might find this useful http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html

Comment: malloc(16) will only allocate enough memory for an int array[0][4].

Answer (score 2):

Using the nice [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/) tool, `int (*m)[4][4]` is translated to `declare m as pointer to array 4 of array 4 of int`, which is multidimensional array. It should work if you allocated more memory.

`int m[10];` is array of 10 integers stacked as a row in memory.
`int (*m)[10];` is a pointer to an array which holds 10 values.

`int m[4][5]` is multidimensional array, but they are almost like `int m[20]`. They are stacked as a row in memory. Indexing `m[2][0]` is simply translated to `m[5*2 + 0]`.

`int *m[5]` is NOT multidimensional array, it is array of pointers. Each pointer points to a different array. Values are not stored in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that 16 bytes ain't enough for your array. Common values of `sizeof(int)` are 2 and 4, so you need at least 32 or 64 bytes for representing 4 `int`s. But **you shouldn't be sticking hard-wired constants into your code anyway.** Use the `sizeof` operator, and it will work:

```
int (*arr)[4][4] = malloc(sizeof(*arr));
int *ptr = &(*arr)[0][0];

// fill it with something, then:

printf("%d = %d\n", (*arr)[1][1], ptr[1 * 4 + 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm playing around pointers and arrays, and i want to cast/convert a pointer to an array of *int* (allocated with *malloc*) to a multidimensional array of *int*.

This is a very good idea. I’ve discovered this year that you can have pointer to arrays, and this is very useful when you want to parse a block of memory like a multidimensional array (because it comes from a `struct` in which the array dimensions can vary, for example). This post is very old, but let’s add an answer.

> I have one more question: what's the difference between the following declarations?
>
> ```c
> int m1[10];
> int (*m2)[10];
> ```

They are not the same at all!

- `m1` is an array of ten integers. It occupies `10 * sizeof(int)` bytes, which is typically 40 bytes.
- `m2` is a pointer to such an array. So it is just a pointer. It can be assigned `NULL`, for instance. It just stores an address. It occupies `sizeof(void *)` bytes, typically 8 bytes nowadays.

When you have an array, you can change it directly to a pointer, and use the pointer the same way you use the array:

```c
int m[10], * mPtr = m;
assert(m[i] == mPtr[i]);
```

This is actually just the same for multidimensional arrays, giving that a multidimensional array is an array of arrays:

```c
int m[10][10], (* mPtr)[10] = m;
assert(m[i][j] == mPtr[i][j]);
```

So when you want a pointer, you have to omit the first dimension, because it is actually not needed to compute the address of a cell. `&mPtr[i][j]` is computed as `mPtr + i * sizeof(int[10]) + j * sizeof(int)` (which is also `mPtr + i * sizeof(*mPtr) + j * sizeof(**mPtr)`. When you go onto the next `i`, it jumps ten ints as you expect.

Hence the solution to your problem:

```c
str->val = malloc(sizeof(int[4][4]));
int (* m)[4] = (int (* )[4])str->val;
```

As a conclusion, C has actually good features/syntaxes to deal with multidimensional arrays, especially matrices. Only the declaration of the pointer is ugly, this is why I commonly use macros for it. See [these test cases](https://gitlab.com/Frigory33/handymacros/-/blob/86c641f6b571c52c20cc32fac91d6c69264b7c50/test/test.c#L47) and [the macro definitions](https://gitlab.com/Frigory33/handymacros/-/blob/86c641f6b571c52c20cc32fac91d6c69264b7c50/src/handymacros.h#L16). For your case, it could be used like that:

```c
PtrDim2(int, m, 4, 4, str->val);
```

To declare and initialize `m` just like above. The first dimension is simply like a comment, actually you can omit it completely if you want: `PtrDim2(int, m, , 4, str->val);`.